Dockerfile file operations are very slow
Building a docker image from a Dockerfile, every file operation (WORKDIR, COPY) seems to take an abnormally long length of time. Approx 5 seconds per file.
Reproduction
File structure:
❯ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   0 Oct 21 14:11 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   0 Oct 21 14:11 b.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   0 Oct 21 14:11 c.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 254 Oct 21 14:43 Dockerfile

Dockerfile:
❯ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY a.txt b.txt c.txt /app/
CMD ["bash"]

Building:
[... omitted for brevity the source image resolving takes less than a second ...]
 => [internal] load build context        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 78B         0.0s
 => [2/3] WORKDIR /app                   4.8s
 => [3/3] COPY a.txt b.txt c.txt /app/   15.3s

Docker info:
❯ docker info                               
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    27.3.1
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.17.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.29.7
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 13
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 12
 Images: 37
 Server Version: 27.3.1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: zfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7f7fdf5fed64eb6a7caf99b3e12efcf9d60e311c
 runc version: v1.1.14-0-g2c9f560
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.8.0-47-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 14
 Total Memory: 46.53GiB
 Name: user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2
 ID: fe886c88-d51a-4a7d-a559-422724cd7e35
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

Logs:
❯ journalctl -u docker.service | cat
Oct 21 15:06:55 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Starting docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 21 15:06:55 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:55.873118721+03:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Oct 21 15:06:55 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:55.874434457+03:00" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.021652863+03:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.297021353+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.757407809+03:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.815279659+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.831713613+03:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled"
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.831750716+03:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled"
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.831780345+03:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=41ca978 containerd-snapshotter=false storage-driver=overlay2 version=27.3.1
Oct 21 15:06:56 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:56.833152363+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Oct 21 15:06:57 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:06:57.854460297+03:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Oct 21 15:06:57 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 21 15:07:07 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:07:07.129955384+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=9847dee6c5d15257d3ad5db6d37396375cc10a8869d1832dee2aeda23ce4cc09 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 21 15:07:31 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: time="2024-10-21T15:07:31.028237289+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8f1faa39acb29c659fb09036d00cf2b31cfca2e28f7ac17cd0171faed0b8b9ec module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 21 15:07:41 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: 2024/10/21 15:07:41 http2: server: error reading preface from client @: read unix /run/docker.sock->@: read: connection reset by peer
Oct 21 15:31:40 user-ThinkPad-E16-Gen-2 dockerd[12143]: 2024/10/21 15:31:40 http2: server: error reading preface from client @: read unix /run/docker.sock->@: read: connection reset by peer

More info:

Ubuntu 24.04.01
The logs (journalctl -u docker.service) show a single http2: server: error reading preface from client @: read unix /run/docker.sock->@: read: connection reset by peer per build (regardless of how many files I copy) and nothing else.
Copying files (or any other file operations) on the host are as fast as you'd expect (instantenous± for copying an empty file).
Disk is not slow, copying a 200MB file took 0.08s. However, the partition is ZFS formatted.
This is running dockerd directly on the host. No virtualization as far as I can tell.
I'm using the default config with default startup settings. I haven't modified anything.
Host has only one disk and only one partition.

Update:

I suspect that the host running ZFS is the culprit. I intend to format the system in the near future and see if that helps.


I haven't tried myself but GitHub issues show some other people having similar issues on some versions. You might try updating docker or if it's the latest version, downgrading it to 4.26.1 i guess.

@ybalcanci I've looked and couldn't find a GitHub issue that describes what I have. Could you link?

More info: Sooo your disc is slow? are you running in virtualization? What is the output of docker info? What filesystem are you using? Where is docker daemon data stored? What filesystem is there? what storage driver does docker use? is your disc slow? What are the docker daemon json settings? how is the docker daemon service file configured or how is docker daemon started? The logs (journalctl -u docker.service) show a singl what else do they show? Can you post all the logs? Is the docker daemon data on the same filesystem as your current working directory? maybe it's copy between fss.

@KamilCuk I think I've narrowed it down to the filesystem being ZFS (TIL that's what they gave me) and the driver being overlay2 which is known to be a buggy combination. But I'll only know when I reinstall and pick I'll add the rest of the details you've requested shortly.

@KamilCuk I've edited to include all the details you've requested, let me know if there's some more.

@Madara'sGhost https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13611 here's the GitHub issue link I checked earlier. Now I see that your problem is very different than that and your suspection seems more relevant. However you might still try to prune docker system (docker system prune -a) and restarting the service as well as downgrading to another version. You never know when those help.

I was running docker daemon on ZFS for years. did you create a zpool in /var/lib/docker ? Follow https://docs.docker.com/engine/storage/drivers/zfs-driver/ . I remember ZFS was really fast, but I think overlay2 on top zfs should also work. Check your zpool list. Maybe docker is creating snapshots of whole root fs? Also, with 15s time, you could attach strace -p <docker_daemon_pid> and check in which syscall it is lagging.
